# How to use Pivot with RowNumber and date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a SQL Server table like this:

[image: SQL-TABLE]

How can I change reading column into 2 columns based on rownumber?

I have tried like this:

```
WITH pivot_data AS
(
    SELECT 
        date, CurrentMeterSNID,
        1 + ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CurrentMeterSNID ORDER BY date desc) - 1) % 2)  rownum,
        Reading
    FROM 
        INF_Facility_ElectricalRecord 
)
SELECT 
    date, CurrentMeterSNID, [1], [2]
FROM 
    pivot_data 
PIVOT 
    (MAX(Reading) FOR rownum IN ([1], [2])) AS p;
```

but the result that I get is:

[image: Result-Image]

I get Null record; how can I replace that null value with record from a day after the date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually you are not doing `PIVOT`. You just want to conditionally display the value on different column. For this you use the `CASE` statement.

For the second requirement : for the NULL value, showing subsequent day value, you can use `LEAD() or LAG()` window function. This is the `else` part of the `case`

```
select  date, CurrentMeterSNID,
        [1] = case when rownum2 = 1 
                   then reading 
                   else lead(reading) over(partition by CurrentMeterSNID order by date)
                   end,
        [2] = case when rownum2 = 2 
                   then reading 
                   else lead(reading) over(partition by CurrentMeterSNID order by date)
                   end
from    INF_Facility_ElectricalRecord
```

Comment: hello, i have tested your code. and i get a result that i want, Thank you so much. but can you explain me what is LEAD() and LAG() and why we need to use them?

Comment: please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are displaying every date in that query, you can't have what you want.
So you have to pick the max(date) in other words where rownumber will be 1.

```
WITH pivot_data AS(
   SELECT date,CurrentMeterSNID,
   1 + ((row_number() over(partition by CurrentMeterSNID ORDER by date desc) - 1) % 2)  rownum,
   Reading
   FROM dbo.Table_1 )
   , T2 AS
   (
SELECT CurrentMeterSNID, date, [1], [2]

FROM pivot_data PIVOT (max(Reading) FOR rownum IN ([1],[2])) AS p
)

SELECT CurrentMeterSNID,  Max(date), MAX([1]), Max([2]) 
FROM T2
GROUP BY CurrentMeterSNID
```